# Django DB design to glob words quickly

Tags: python, django, database-design, glob

I need to quickly look up words for a web application that I am writing in Django.  I was thinking of putting each character of the word in an integerfield of its own, indexed by position.

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    length = models.IntegerField()

    c0 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    mapping = [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4,]

    def save(self):
        self.length = len(self.word)
        for (idx, char) in enumerate(self.word):
            self.mapping[idx] = ord(char)
        models.Model.save(self)
```

Then I could make queries like `Word.objects.filter(length=4, mapping[2]=ord('A'))` to find all words of length four that have an A in the third position.

I'm not really sure about the design and some of the mechanics so I thought I would ask for suggestions here before I went and tried to implement it.  I'm not entirely sure about the syntax for making queries.

So, I guess the questions would be

1. Do you have any suggestions for the design?
2. Would `mapping[2]` work?
3. Would I be able to pass in a dictionary to the filter command so that I can have a variable number of keyword arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell more details, how many words are these and why you need to lookup for them quickly and how quickly?

Comment: I'm optimizing a backtracking constraint satisfaction program for generating crosswords.  Right now I've got approximately 42,000 unique words and phrases.  They are stripped of everything but alphabetic uppercase characters and stored in all caps.  I ran cProfile on my algorithm and right now I spend the majority of the time getting candidates from the dictionary (I am currently using fnmatch on a list of words -- something quick and dirty to see if I got things right before I began optimizing).  The faster I can do it the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would mapping[2] work?

No, it wouldn't.

> Would I be able to pass in a dictionary to the filter command so that I can have a variable number of keyword arguments?

Certainly. For instance:

```
conditions = dict(word__startswith = 'A', length = 5)
Word.objects.filter(**conditions)
```

would find all `Word` instances starting with `A` and are five characters long.

> Do you have any suggestions for the design?

This feels to me is like a case of premature optimization. I suspect that for moderate volumes of data you should be able to combine a suitable database function with Django's filter to get what you need.

For example:

> to find all words of length four that have an A in the third position.

you can combine a Django filter with (Postgresql's) [`strpos`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

```
contains, position = 'A', 3
where = ["strpos(word, '%s') = %s" % (contains, position)]
Word.objects.filter(length = 4, word__contains = contains).extra(where = where)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'm dealing with about 42,000 words (in the near future I plan to have many more) and for a call to the backend I need to do about six to eight hundred partial dictionary lookups.  word__startswith won't work because I need to be able to find patterns like '??SH??' among others (I'm generating crosswords, I should have said that -- sorry).  I didn't know about the strpos filter with Postgresql.  Does that work with sqlite3 or nonrel/appengine?  Thanks again!

Comment: `Does that work with sqlite3 or nonrel/appengine?`:  I'm sorry, I don't know if there is an equivalent of `strpos` for SQLite or nonrel/appengine.

Comment: Thanks!  I used your suggestion of specifying the conditions using a dictionary!